# Does the IDOR vulnerability have to be sensitive data?

Tags: appsec, bug-bounty

I had a hard time convincing a bug I reported that it was a bug bounty program. It seems to be more of a discussion than a question.

Scenario: Users shop on the shopping site. The categories of these purchases are drawn from an endpoint under the name of "favorite categories". Since the userId parameter is used here, and in a non-authenticated way, it turns out in which categories the user shopped with a different user ID. It is an openness that does not make sense directly and on its own. But technically it is a vulnerability.

Also, wouldn't it be credible to look at which category the person whose User ID I have captured is shopping in and then to perform a related phishing attack scenario according to that?

Sample : `/api/favorite-categories?userId=87df45cd-1111-4222-1111-a5222cdd6222`

Do [IDOR vulnerabilities](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Insecure_Direct_Object_Reference_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) need to contain sensitive data in the response?

Therefore, should the company close this vulnerability? Or is it difficult to consider it a vulnerability?

Comment: I removed the "should the bug hunter get paid?" part of the question since that's purely a function of the bug bounty policy.

Comment: Thanks. My purpose in asking was that the company said this is not a vulnerability and they will not pay me.

Comment: Let me ask you this: if a 'vulnerability' has no negative impact, is it a vulnerability?

Comment: (1) It looks like the user ID is a UUID. Are you able to find and/or enumerate UUIDs? (2) Are you able to associate the UUID with other information about the user? Can you find Bob's favorite categories? Or get favorite categories for a random user and then figure out who that user is?

Comment: Yes I can get GUID values but I don't know who they are, that part is a different discussion. But the impact of the subject I mentioned seems very low. Syned and you guys gave a good answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your question it seems like you are able to get the favorite categories of a user, provided that you know UUID. I'd like to ask some same question as @Thomas did, are you able to get UUID of other users?

Assuming that you did somehow, what's the impact of the vulnerability? Does this vulnerability hold enough threat for the customers or the company? You said you can do a phishing attack on the customers, is that in the scope of engagement?

In my opinion, most of the companies will mark it as a low severity vulnerability at max as you are only able to get "favourite categories" of a user, which doesn't hold any sensitive information about user.

To escalate a low severity to a higher severity, you need to increase the impact of the vulnerability. Incase of IDOR, that can be either done by sensitive information leakage or by doing a sensitive action on other users.

To mark the severity of the vulnerability is at the total discretion of the company, as an external researcher you can only convince them. And they hold the right to evaluate the risk of the vulnerability. It might sound like a vulnerability to you, but they might evaluate that cost of patching a vulnerability is more than the risk it holds.

Comment: I understand very well. Thank you for your answer. You are right, it creates a very specific situation. Its impact is very low.